# Backup and Restore Realm file iOS

Tags: ios, swift, realm, restore, backups

Are there any clear directions on how to create backups and restores of Realm files for iOS and swift? Thank you very much.

Comment: Where do you want to back it up exactly?

Comment: The standard backup included with iCloud (or to your computer) backs up your Realm files as long as they are in the default location. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I would like to manually have the user backup/restore files to ‘Backup’ sub-directory of the documents directory. I would like to back it up locally on the device so that when the app is upgraded, the user’s data is persistent.

Comment: If you're using Realm, that data is already local. If you want to copy a file, that would be done through OS level calls. At this point you should attempt to write some code and then when you get stuck, let us know and we'll take a look. In the meantime, please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)